# Error when checking target: Expected output to have shape (None, 4) but got array with shape (30,3)

Tags: python, image, keras, medical

I am working on training a VGG16-like model in Keras. I am using TAM dataset and got this error.
I read multiple similar issues but none helped me so far.

Here is the Code

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_weights, save_best_only=False, verbose=0)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.2, patience=10, min_lr=0.00001)

history = model.fit_generator(
            generator=train_batches,
            steps_per_epoch=10,
            epochs=5,
            callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr],
            validation_data=valid_batches,
            validation_steps=100,
            verbose=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your generator (or your model) is wrong. Your model expects one shape and got other. Please, post your full code, or more details, for we can help you.